# Populating selected items at the right box of DualListBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [this](https://github.com/Geodan/DualListBox)  plugin to create a DualListBox for a selection field for a form in twitter-bootstrap-3. The form is created for edition purpose. So i am trying to add the previously selected values in the right-sided box. And also non-selected values are added manually.

To achieve this i have collected data from a JSON and make options string manually. Here is my code -

```
// Getting data related to the country of operations
    $.getJSON(country_of_operation_json_url)
        .done(function (data) {
            var options = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var a = 1;
                for (var j = 0; j < port_ids.length; j++) {
                    // Appending "selected" attribute to the values which are already selected
                    if (port_ids[j] == data[i]["id"]) {
                        options += '<options value="' + data[i]["id"] + '" selected="selected">' + data[i]["port_iso"] + '</options>';
                        a = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (a == 1) {
                    options += '<options value="' + data[i]["id"] + '">' + data[i]["port_iso"] + '</options>';
                }
            }

            // Appending the options at the selected box of the dual box
            $("select#country-of-operation-edit").empty().append(options);

            // Loading Country of operating dual-box field
            $("#country-of-operation-edit").DualListBox();

        });
```

Here is the html file that is generating select field -

```
<div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Country of operation</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" data-json="false" id="country-of-operation-edit">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Problem is there are no values showing in the field. Here is the screenshot -

[image]

I couldn't find what am i doing wrong here. If this is not the way to populate the DualListbox with values, what are the other ways? Any help would be appreciated much. I am stuck here for hours.

**EDIT-1:** Here is my json - http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb7e1573

**EDIT-2:** For checking, you can take this values as selected -

```
port_ids = ["41", " 47", " 61"]
```

Comment: do you really need ajax to get the values?

Comment: Yes. I need to take the values from external source and filter some of them as "selected".

Comment: what about errors?

Comment: There are no errors showing. I have checked  the boxes with inspect element. No data is loading as options inside select tags. I have checked the options string also. It is generating properly.

Comment: in the console not on the page, man

Comment: There are no errors in the console. :)

Comment: does your json file have any values?

Comment: Yes. It has. As i have said earlier, i have checked the options string. It is generating nicely from JSON according to my recommendation. Let me share my json. It will take few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `options` to `option` man :)

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var a = 1;
                for (var j = 0; j < port_ids.length; j++) {
                    // Appending "selected" attribute to the values which are already selected
                    if (port_ids[j] == data[i]["id"]) {
                        options += '<option value="' + data[i]["id"] + '" selected="selected">' + data[i]["port_iso"] + '</option>';
                        a = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (a == 1) {
                    options += '<option value="' + data[i]["id"] + '">' + data[i]["port_iso"] + '</option>';
                }
            }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hh2zrt82/

Comment: wow, thanks. A simple-tiny mistake can lead to hours of frustration. Much appreciated. :)  By the way, i was about to open bounty for this question. Luckily, my reputations have survived.